# Why XDocument can't get element out of this wellform XML text?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get the value of the `Address` element from the following XML text, but it's not finding it unless I remove `xmlns="http://www.foo.com"` from the `Root` element. However, the XML is valid even with it. What's the problem here?

Since I'm getting the XML text from a web service, I don't have control over it, but I can strip out the `xmlns` part if I have to as the last resort.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns="http://www.foo.com">
  <Address>Main St SW</Address>
</Root>
```

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlTextAbove);
var address = doc.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name == "Address").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(address.Value); // <-- error, address is null.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your xml contains a namespace, you have to mention that in code. This will work:

```
    XNamespace nsSys = "http://www.foo.com";
    XElement xDoc = XElement.Load("1.xml");
    XElement xEl2 = xDoc.Descendants(nsSys + "Address").FirstOrDefault();
```

However I had to change your xml a little bit, as it contained repeated `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` which should occur only once per xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns="http://www.foo.com" >
  <Address>Main St SW</Address>
</Root>
```

Related article in MSDN: [XNamespace Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

The document root's XML namespace is included in the textual representation of `o.Name`, which is actually an instance of [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) so the condition never matches.

The easiest fix is to use [`LocalName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx) for the comparison:

```
.Where(o => o.Name.LocalName == "Address")
```

Comment: +2 I didn't know this either.

Comment: +3 coz ive been working on this since yesterday. thanks :)