# Why can I not read XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why XDocument can’t get element out of this wellform XML text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390749/why-xdocument-cant-get-element-out-of-this-wellform-xml-text)

I'm trying to read an xml using linq to xml, and i guess i'm understanding something wrong.
This is the start of the xml (it's long so i'm not posting it all)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
      <Body>
         <ReportItems>
             <Tablix Name="Tablix12">
              ......
              ......
             </Tablix>
```

This xml could have a few of "Tablix" elements, and might have 1 or none, for each one of these i want to read whats inside this tag and i'm having difficulty to start.

I have tried a few ways to get the "Tablix" elements, or any other element.
In this code i get a result only for the "var root", the rest of them are always null and i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

```
    public ReadTablixResponse ReadTablixAdvanced(string rdl)
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(rdl);

        var root = xml.Root;
        var Body = xml.Root.Element("Body");
        var report = xml.Root.Element("Report");
        var aa = xml.Element("Report");
        var bb = xml.Element("Body");
        var test = xml.Elements("Tablix");
```

Comment: The obvious problems are that you're not handling namespaces in your code (that matters!) and that you're not respecting the structure of the document. Whether or not there are other issues, the two I've identified *will* cause problems for you until you address them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing i noticed, is that you used the method `Element("name")`. which will always try to retrun the first (in document order) **direct** child element with the specified XName . and that is probebly why you got **null**.

if you want to return deeper elements(from where you looking). you need to use the Descendants("name") method, which will return a collection of all descendants elements . no matter how deep they are (relative to your chosen anchor)...

for example:

```
 XNamespace xNameSpace = "http://schemas.micro.....";
 // ...
 var tablixes= xml.Descendants(xNameSpace + "Tablix");
```

which you can then wolk through:

```
foreach (var tablix in tablixes)
{
    var name=(string)tablix.Attribute("Name");
    var age=(int)tablix.Element("age");
   ...

}
```

Comment: This as is also returned null.
When i added the xNameSpace to this, it returned the "Tablix" elements
This is what i used:
"var tb = xml.Descendants(xNameSpace + "Tablix");"

Comment: noted, I improved my answer according to your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(rdl);
        XNamespace xNameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition";
        var tablixes= from o in xDocument.Descendants(xNameSpace + "Tablix")
                    select o.Value;
```

Comment: This is not really helping, maybe i didn't explain my self properly
In side the Tablix there is much more information i need to read, it has more elements and attributes that i later need to read and extract.
I'm not sure how to work wiith the var tablixes that this generates, i'm not sure this is what i need